# Backbone model not allowing me to get data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am very new to Backbone and am doing a simple tutorial.  I keep running into an error that I dont understand.  Here is my code.

```
(function($) {
    dataModel = new Backbone.Model.extend({
        data: [
        {text: "Google", href: "www.google.com"},
        {text: "Yahoo", href: "www.yahoo.com"},
        {text: "Youtube", href: "www.youtube.com"},
        ]
    });

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.template = $('#list-template').children();
    },
    el: $('#container'),
    events: {
        "click button": "render"
    },
    render: function(){
        var data = this.model.get('data');
        for(var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++){
            var li = this.template.clone().find('a').attr('href', data[i].href).text(data[i].text).end();
            this.el.find('ul').append(li);
        }
    }
});

var view = new View({ model: dataModel });
})(jQuery);
```

When I call `this.model.get('data')` I get the error `TypeError: Object function (){return a.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'get'`.  Please show me my error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the properties and methods you pass when extending a model are set on its prototype not as its attributes, and `dataModel` here is not a Backbone model instance but a Backbone Model subclass. If done this way to access the data property you'd need to instantiate the model and do a `modelInstance.data` rather then `modelInstance.get('data')` as if it would be when data would be set as model attribute as shown in the example below.

What you wanted to do here was

```
var dataModel = new Backbone.Model({ // without the extend!
    data: [
    {text: "Google", href: "www.google.com"},
    {text: "Yahoo", href: "www.yahoo.com"},
    {text: "Youtube", href: "www.youtube.com"},
    ]
});
```

as you want to create an instance of a model rather then subclass Backbone.Model class. `Extend` method is used to subclass core Backbone classes – views, models, collections and routers.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'dataModel' is just the definition of the Model. You need to create a model instance by calling `new dataModel()` when you pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

a model define`s only the structure of one data element

```
Model
    defaults:
       text : null
       href : null
```

what you need is a Collection

```
Collection
    model : Model
```

you can then set data to the collection with .add

```
Collection.add([
    {text: "Google", href: "www.google.com"},
    {text: "Yahoo", href: "www.yahoo.com"},
    {text: "Youtube", href: "www.youtube.com"},
])
```

to get the data from the collection look here
http://underscorejs.org/#collections

Hope it helps